# How can I map multiple images on the sphere with C++/OpenGL?

Tags: c++, opengl

Is there anyone know how to map multiple images on the sphere using C++/OpenGL?

As the picture here;
[images on sphere](http://www.flickr.com/photos/80647638@N05/7395304126/in/photostream)

Answer (score 1):

You can split the sphere in multiple sections, each one having bound a single image.

It should be reltively easy to generate a sphere slice coordinate using sphere equation.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow: thanks us by accepting the answer! ;)

Answer (score 0):

You could just combine all the images into a single texture using an image editing program. Then you would only have to apply a single texture over the entire sphere. To do this you would just need to find a way to import a model of a sphere into your program.  (Unless you want to try generating one procedurally.)

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is creating texture images with alpha channel.
You can add many texture into shader code and blend them all by alpha as masking.